# How do I extract the part of a string whose individual words begin with letters?

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I'm using Ruby 2.4.  Let's say I have a string that has a number of spaces in it

```
str = "abc def 123ffg"
```

How do I capture all the consecutive words at the beginning of the string that begin with a letter?  So for example, in the above, I would want to capture

```
"abc def"
```

And if I had a string like

```
"aa22 b    cc 33d  ff"
```

I would want to capture

```
"aa22 b    cc"
```

but if my string were

```
"66dd eee ff"
```

I would want to return nothing because the first word of that string does not begin with a letter.

Comment: Could your string be `"ab12 $ab"`? If not you should say that the string contains only letters, digits and spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can spare the extra spaces between words, you could then `split` the string and iterate the resulting array with `take_while`, using a regex to get the desired output; something like this:

```
str = "abc def 123ffg"
str.split.take_while { |word| word[0] =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }
#=> ["abc", "def"]
```

The output is an array, but if a string is needed, you could use `join` at the end:

```
str.split.take_while { |word| word[0] =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }.join(" ")
#=> "abc def"
```

---

More examples:

```
"aa22 b    cc 33d  ff".split.take_while { |word| word[0] =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }
#=> ["aa22", "b", "cc"]

"66dd eee ff".split.take_while { |word| word[0] =~ /[[:alpha:]]/ }
#=> []
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sub` method can be used to replace with an empty string `''` everything that needs to be removed from the expression.

In this case, a first `sub` method is needed to remove the whole text if it starts with a digit. Then another `sub` will remove everything starting from any word that starts with a digit.

**Answer:**

```
str.sub(/^\d+.*/, '').sub(/\s+\d+.*/, '')
```

**Outputs:**

```
str = "abc def 123ffg"
# => "abc def"

str = "aa22 b    cc 33d  ff"
# => "aa22 b    cc"

str = "66dd eee ff"
# => ""
```

Answer (score 0):

### The Regular Expression

There's usually more than one way to match a pattern, although some are simpler than others. A relatively simple regular express that works with your inputs and expected outputs is as follows:

```
/(?:(?:\A|\s*)\p{L}\S*)+/
```

This matches one or more strings when all of the following conditions are met:

1. start-of-string, or zero or more whitespace characters
2. followed by a Unicode category of "letter"
3. followed by zero or more non-whitespace characters

The first item in the list, which is the second non-capturing group, is what allows the match to be repeated until a word starts with a non-letter.

### The Proofs

```
regex = /(?:(?:\A|\s*)\p{L}\S*)+/

regex.match 'aa22 b    cc 33d  ff' #=> #<MatchData "aa22 b    cc">
regex.match 'abc def 123ffg'       #=> #<MatchData "abc def">
regex.match '66dd eee ff'          #=> #<MatchData "">
```